# How to follow a Link to a User in Cloud Code?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In an afterSave Cloud Code function as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Post", function (request) {

    var post = request.object;

    if (post.has('author')) {
        var author = post.get('author');  
        // author is a Link to a specific Parse.User   
    }

}
```

I am trying to get the email of the Parse user pointed to by the Post's author field.

In the above example, `author` ends up containing the following:

```
{
    "__type":"Pointer",
    "className":"_User",
    "objectId":"413wgL9vf1"
}
```

Essentially, I want to read the `email` property of the user pointed to by the pointer.

I tried doing `author.get('email')` and that failed, saying "undefined". The email is set in the database.

What's the right way to do this? Should I be writing a query against the User class using the objectId from the link, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was `author.fetch().then(...)`.